# Grouping the nested attribute list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
lst = ['orb|2|3|4', 'obx|2|3|4', 'orb|2|3|4', 'obx|1|2|3', 'obx|1|2|3','obx|1|2|3']
```

How can I group the list by the initial three lines, so that in the end it's like this. Grouping occurs on three characters of the line. If the line starts with "orb", then subsequent lines are added to the list that begins with this line. Thanks for the answer.

```
result = [['orb|2|3|4', 'obx|2|3|4'], ['orb|2|3|4', 'obx|1|2|3', 'obx|1|2|3','obx|1|2|3']]
```

Comment: I think there is a mistake in your desired output.

Comment: The problem statement is a bit unclear - I see that English isn't your primary language, I want to help clarifying the question - and making sure the answer you got is actually working. Text says 'lines starting with 'obx' are added to the list that begins with that line", but output example groups 'obx' lines with the *previous* line. Can you have multiple items that DON'T start with 'obx' (e.g. [ "orb1", "orca3", ...])? Is your goal to group a line without 'obx' with *all* lines after it that have 'obx'? Note the title is misleading, too: there is nothing 'attribute' related in the question.

Comment: Hello. English is not my native language. My goal is to get a list of lists that begin with a given string. That is, I need to go through the list. And the lines that follow the line, which begins with the "orb", should be in the list from the given string. Thank you for understanding

Comment: OK, so actually, lines starting with "orb|" are to be treated as "start of group" and everything that follows up to the next "orb|" item goes into one group (and anything that's NOT 'orb' is just things to add to the group. E.g., this [orb|1, orb|2, xyz|7, aaa, orb|4, ccc, orb|5] is to become:
[ [orb|1], [orb|2,xyz|7,aaa], [orb|4,ccc], [orb|5]]. (NOTE: not clear what to do if the first item in the input list doesn't start with "orb").

Comment: If the first element does not begin with the "orb", then it must be skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an algorithm of `O(N)` complexity:

```
res = []
tmp = []
for x in lst:
    if x.startswith('orb'):
        if tmp:
            res.append(tmp)
        tmp = [x]
    elif tmp:
        tmp.append(x)
res.append(tmp)
```

result:

```
In [133]: res
Out[133]:
[['orb|2|3|4', 'obx|2|3|4'],
 ['orb|2|3|4', 'obx|1|2|3', 'obx|1|2|3', 'obx|1|2|3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools, re
lst = ['orb|2|3|4', 'obx|2|3|4', 'orb|2|3|4', 'obx|1|2|3', 'obx|1|2|3','obx|1|2|3']
new_result = [list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda x:re.findall('^\w+', x)[0])]
final_result = [new_result[i]+new_result[i+1] for i in range(0, len(new_result), 2)]
```

Output:

```
[['orb|2|3|4', 'obx|2|3|4'], ['orb|2|3|4', 'obx|1|2|3', 'obx|1|2|3', 'obx|1|2|3']]
```

Comment: This won't work if you have two subsequent items that don't start with 'obx', e.g., the description seems to imply that ["orb|1", "orb|2", "orb|3", "obx|4", "obx|5"] should be grouped as [["orb|1"], ["orb|2"], ["orb|3", "obx|4", "obx|5"]]. Likewise, it will simply fail with IndexError if you remove the last 3 items from the input.

Comment: This code is beautiful, but it does not work as I need it. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: @SerhiiYaroshevkyi As LeoK pointed out, your question is still not at all clear. How specifically is the answer not working? What cases are failing?

Comment: The problem is that the lines that begin with the "orb" can be larger. Therefore I get an error "IndexError: list index out of range". In any case, thank you very much.

Comment: @SerhiiYaroshevkyi No problem. Please post an example of what you mean, with your desired output.

Comment: lst = ['MSH|^~\\&|CENTRUM|', 'ORC|RE|100003883', 'OBR|1|100003883', 'OBX|1|NM|', 'OBX|1|NM|', 'ORC|RE|100003883-11469', 'OBR|2|100003883', 'OBX|1|NM|', 'OBX|1|NM|', 'OBX|1|NM|', 'ORC|RE|100003883', 'OBR|3|100003883', 'OBX|1|', 'ORC|RE|100003883', 'OBR|4|100003883', 'OBX|1|NM|277933']

Comment: result = [['ORC|RE|100003883', 'OBR|1|100003883', 'OBX|1|NM|', 'OBX|1|NM|'], ['ORC|RE|100003883-11469', 'OBR|2|100003883', 'OBX|1|NM|', 'OBX|1|NM|', 'OBX|1|NM|'], ['ORC|RE|100003883', 'OBR|3|100003883', 'OBX|1|'], ['ORC|RE|100003883', 'OBR|4|100003883', 'OBX|1|NM|277933']]

Comment: @SerhiiYaroshevky `'MSH|^~\\&|CENTRUM|'` appears to be missing from `result` Why is that?

Comment: If the list starts, from the line without the value of "ORC", then it must be skipped

Comment: In which case, you can prompt in which side you need to move to solve this problem. Thank you so much.